# Why are these tables not aligning properly?

Tags: html, css

I have to create some tables as an assignment as I started learning HTML and CSS. These are what I am trying to create,

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM0n9.jpg)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTr7A.jpg)

Code:
**TABLE 1 -**
This table seems to makes the fourth row remain in the third row for some reason.

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="17">My Work Plan for the Week</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">July</td>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="3">Monday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Tuesday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Wednesday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Thursday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Friday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Week 1</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">Meeting at ABC-123 Ltd</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">Business Lunch at 1pm</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">Project due by 5pm</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">Web Conference in London</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">Early Finish (4pm)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Week 2</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">Business Planning Lunch - 1:30pm</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="9">Networking and Training Conference</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Early Finish (4pm)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**TABLE 2 -**
I can't properly set the boxes to the desired size as in the image.

```css
tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.big {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="red" class="big">0</td>
      <td class="blue">1</td>
      <td class="yellow">2</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="green" class="big">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="orange" class="big">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="green" class="big">5</td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="yellow" class="big">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="blue">7</td>
      <td class="red">8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `rowspan` from your last two rows `td`...it causing your `tr` alignment issue

***Stack Snippet***

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="17">My Work Plan for the Week</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">July</td>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="3">Monday</th>
    <th colspan="3">Tuesday</th>
    <th colspan="3">Wednesday</th>
    <th colspan="3">Thursday</th>
    <th colspan="3">Friday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Week 1</td>
    <td colspan="3">Meeting at ABC-123 Ltd</td>
    <td colspan="3">Business Lunch at 1pm</td>
    <td colspan="3">Project due by 5pm</td>
    <td colspan="3">Web Conference in London</td>
    <td colspan="3">Early Finish (4pm)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Week 2</td>
    <td colspan="3">Business Planning Lunch - 1:30pm</td>
    <td colspan="9">Networking and Training Conference</td>
    <td>Early Finish (4pm)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

And in second table you are using `class` attribute twice which causing the problem...combine both classes into one `class` attribute

***Stack Snippet***

```css
tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

td.big {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="red big">0</td>
      <td class="blue">1</td>
      <td class="yellow">2</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="green big">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="orange big">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="green big">5</td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="yellow big">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="blue">7</td>
      <td class="red">8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="17">My Work Plan for the Week</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">July</td>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
      <th colspan="3">Monday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Tuesday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Wednesday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Thursday</th>
      <th colspan="3">Friday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >Week 1</td>
      <td  colspan="3">Meeting at ABC-123 Ltd</td>
      <td  colspan="3">Business Lunch at 1pm</td>
      <td colspan="3">Project due by 5pm</td>
      <td  colspan="3">Web Conference in London</td>
      <td  colspan="3">Early Finish (4pm)</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Week 2</td>
      <td colspan="3">Business Planning Lunch - 1:30pm</td>
      <td colspan="9">Networking and Training Conference</td>
      <td colspan="3">Early Finish (4pm)</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```